# Compare two JSONObject values and return the smaller between them

Tags: android, json

For the given JSON:

```
{
    "month": {
        "days": {
            "day1": {
                "start": 13914323164815,
                "duration": 15
            },
            "day2": {
                "start": 13914123164815,
                "duration": 56
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the values for **duration** (in this case **15** and **56**), compare them and return the smaller value. First i got the **month** object and this is what i tried next:

```
JSONObject days = myMonthObject.getJSONObject("days");
JSONArray daysArray = days.names();
    for (short r = 0; r<daysArray.length();r++){
             String dayObject = daysArray.getString(r);
             JSONObject allDaysObject = days.getJSONObject(dayObject); 
             String duration = allDaysObject.getString("duration"); 
             Log.w(TAG, "THE DURATION IS: " + duration);
}
```

On the first iteration I got the message: 
THE DURATION IS: 15,
and on the second iteration: THE DURATION IS: 56.

Now how to preserve the first found value for **duration** and on the next iteration of **daysArray** loop (the value will be **56**) to compare both and return and smaller?

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, hope this helps:

```
int minValue = 99999; 
int index = 0;
for (int f = 0; f < daysArray.length(); f++){
String dayObject = daysArray.getString(f);
JSONObject allDaysObject = days.getJSONObject(dayObject); 
String duration = allDaysObject.getString("duration");

if(Integer.valueOf(duration) < minValue){
    minValue = Integer.valueOf(duration);
    index = f;                                                      
    }
}
String dayObject = daysArray.getString(index);
    JSONObject allDaysObject = days.getJSONObject(dayObject); 
    String duration = allDaysObject.getString("duration");
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, outisde the loop, create an int variable called max.

```
int max = 0;
```

Essentially, you're getting the value of each duration as a String (as in the example):

```
String duration = allDaysObject.getString("duration");
```

Now, you can get the int value of this by:

```
int intDuration = Integer.parseInt(duration);
```

Next, compare intDuration to max:

```
if (intDuration > max) max = intDuration;
```

Then you can let this iterate through the entire array. At the end of the loop, max will hold the highest duration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want to return the smaller value, not the larger. Can you tell me how to do it? :)

Comment: Well, just change the '>' sign to a '<' sign.

Comment: Well, i have tried that and it did not work. Thanks anyway, i have figured it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a variable

```
String tmpDuration;
//in the for loop
if(tmpDuration.equals("") || duration < tmpDuration){
    tmpDuration = duration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying much what you've

```
int min = 0;    

JSONObject days = myMonthObject.getJSONObject("days");
JSONArray daysArray = days.names();
for (int i = 0; i < daysArray.lenght(); i++){
    JSONObject day = daysArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String duration= day.getString("duration");
    if(i = 0) {
        min = Integer.valueOf(duration);
    } else {
        if (Integer.valueOf(duration) < min) {
            min = Integer.valueOf(duration);
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you what the Object that has the highest duration

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
TreeMap<String,Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>(bcv);

JSONObject days = myMonthObject.getJSONObject("days");
JSONArray daysArray = days.names();

for (JSONObject day : daysArray){
    map.put(day.toString(), Integer.valueOf(day.getString("duration"));
}

sorted_map.putAll(map);

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Integer> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String,Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

This should return

> JSONObject  "day1": {
>               "start": 13914323164815,
>               "duration": 15
>
> 15

I´ve taken the TreeMap code from here, any retribution for this goes to user157196:

> [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but i want to return the smaller value, not the larger. How to do it? :)

Comment: I´m sorry, the code I provided does return the smallest value not 56 but 15. If you navigate throught the link I posted on my answer the output of the code it´s sorted by ascending values. Just iterate the hashmap and get the first value to obtain the smallest one.

Comment: @taxo I also corrected the short answer to fulfill the condition on min value.

Comment: @ axierjhtjz sorry, i forgot to write :( I still could not get the smaller duration, by anyway i resolved my problem! Thanks! :)